# About the status bar frame change

Tags: ios

My question is that when I am talking or sharing hotspot，then when I turn into my APP，the tabbar will down 20 pt，but if I am using APP，then I turn to share or make a talk ,this problem will not appear， I am using storyboard to build my App..

Comment: The question is too vague

Comment: While in the operation of the APP, communication and sharing of hot show the status bar will not change the tabbar and navigationbar frame, if you start the APP when calling or share in the hot, can let a tabbar and navigationbar frame change